# Could not load the module

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new to Python and Flask module. I got an error after running my code. My code look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from sqlalchemy import sql
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = sql(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I need to proceed this code to create a website. However, I got an error from `line 7`, that is:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not directly use the `sqlalchemy` package (and you are doing it wrong, anyway). The correct way of using SQLAlchemy with Flask is:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: @LAI In that case simply use `flask_sqlalchemy`. I have updated the answer. You should install it using `pip` if you haven't already done so: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/

Comment: @LAI It is `flask-sqlalchemy` (with a dash instead of an underscore). Please also read the documentation as we can't provide all the information here as comments.

Comment: For your information @Selcuk, I still cannot install the module by using the command. Any solution can solve it? Is it version problem or anything?

Comment: It is certainly on PyPI. You must be doing something wrong. Double check your command: https://pypi.org/project/Flask-SQLAlchemy/

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this, use flask_sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: My Flask library don't have this flask_sqlalchemy module, I have tried this way before, but still cannot work.

Comment: OK, another answer is quite good, I think that is just the right answer you want.